# Where can I pick up a coin magnet?

Tags: altos-adventure

One of the goals is to "pick up a coin magnet". It apparently isn't one of the Workshop items, so where/how can I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the red glowing icons you see occasionally as you play, the power-up that makes you attract coins. If you look very close you'll see the red icon is shaped like a horseshoe magnet.